# Creating a mini piano in arduino

Tags: arduino

I'm helping my cousin with a uni project that involves creating an arduino mini piano, but there's a problem with the code used.
The code she is using plays every note one by one without touching any button.

If someone could enlight me in a way to resolve the error please do.

The code: (c++)

```
void setup()
{
  pinMode(0, INPUT);
  pinMode(8, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(1, INPUT);
  pinMode(2, INPUT);
  pinMode(3, INPUT);
  pinMode(4, INPUT);
  pinMode(5, INPUT);
  pinMode(6, INPUT);
 
}

void loop()
{
  if (digitalRead(0) == 1) {
    tone(8, 262, 100); // play tone 48 (C4 = 262 Hz)
    delay(600); // Wait for 300 millisecond(s)
  }
  if (digitalRead(1) == 1) {
    tone(8, 294, 100); // play tone 50 (D4 = 294 Hz)
    delay(600); // Wait for 300 millisecond(s)
  }
  if (digitalRead(2) == 1) {
    tone(8, 330, 100); // play tone 52 (E4 = 330 Hz)
    delay(600); // Wait for 300 millisecond(s)
  }
  if (digitalRead(3) == 1) {
    tone(8, 349, 100); // play tone 53 (F4 = 349 Hz)
    delay(600); // Wait for 300 millisecond(s)
  }
  if (digitalRead(4) == 1) {
    tone(8, 392, 100); // play tone 55 (G4 = 392 Hz)
    delay(600); // Wait for 300 millisecond(s)
  }
  if (digitalRead(5) == 1) {
    tone(8, 440, 100); // play tone 57 (A4 = 440 Hz)
    delay(600); // Wait for 300 millisecond(s)
  }
  if (digitalRead(6) == 1) {
    tone(8, 494, 100); // play tone 59 (B4 = 494 Hz)
    delay(600); // Wait for 300 millisecond(s)
  }

}
```

Comment: I *think* you should use `HIGH` instead of `1`, but I am unsure whether that will help. Did you check [this tutorial on arduino.cc](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/muhammad-aqib/arduino-button-tutorial-using-arduino-digitalread-function-08adb5)?

Comment: I have no experience with arduino, but what does `digitalRead` `return` if no buttons are pressed?

Comment: Which Arduino are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's nothing wrong with the code, if the intended behavior is to play one tone at time ( the one whose button is clicked ). There's probably something wrong with the way the buttons are linked to the Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

you maybe need to verify the buttons connection you're using, if they'are pulled-up, you need to change : digitalRead(x) == 1  >>> digitalRead(x) == 0
for all the pins ...